# Jekyll site won't display on GitHub Pages

Tags: github, jekyll, github-pages

I am trying to use GitHub Pages with Jekyll. I have created a repo named:`myusername.github.io` where `myusername` is exactly the same as my github username. I am using Jekyll to create the site. I have it setup locally on my machine and have tested the page using:

`jekyll serve`

There are no issues running the site locally. I have pushed the Jekyll site to my repo. However, when I go to `myusername.github.io` I just see a blank white page. What am I doing wrong here? I have tested to see if GitHub Pages is working by adding an `index.html` file to the repo and this will display correctly. However for some reason the Jekyll site is not displaying at all. What am I doing wrong here?

EDIT:

My process to create the page was like so:

```
jekyll new mysite
cd mysite
git init
git add .
git remote add origin https://github.com/myusername/myusername.github.io.git
git push -u origin master
```

repo looks like this:

[image]

Comment: Have you checked to see if there were any [build errors](https://help.github.com/articles/viewing-jekyll-build-error-messages/)?

Comment: how do I do this?

Comment: You should be able to follow the link in my comment which shows you how to do that.

Comment: Just checked. No build errors displayed there at all. It also runs fine locally.

Comment: @Aurora0001 edited my question with more details.

Comment: Very odd. Have you tried checking viewing the source of your page to see what's happening?

Comment: @Aurora0001 yes nothing. Just a blank html file

Answer (score 1):

While your site is properly setup to use `jekyll`, it's probably using ruby gems that are not available to `github-pages`.

The only lines that you're supposed to have in your Gemfile are:

```
source 'https://rubygems.org'
gem 'github-pages', group: :jekyll_plugins
```

Any other gems or includes may not be available to Github Pages, causing the `jeykll` biuld to fail

Comment: Copied this text into the Gemfile in the repo and still not showing anything. There are also no Jekyll build errors displayed in the settings for the page.

Comment: Do I need to do anything to the Gemfile.lock?

Comment: Does it build locally anymore? I'm guessing not