# Discrepancy between GitHub Pages and locally hosted Jekyll site

Tags: css, jekyll, github-pages, minima

I'm encountering an odd style difference between my locally hosted Jekyll site and the live site, on GitHub Pages. More specifically, the site shows up with the correct format locally—but with garbled formatting on the live version. I've examined related questions, linked below, but none of them have provided a workable solution.

- [Jekyll site works locally but not on Github Pages](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42450554/jekyll-site-works-locally-but-not-on-github-pages)
- [Local Jekyll Serve/Live Site discrepancy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39561412/local-jekyll-serve-live-site-discrepancy)
- [Jekyll site won't display on GitHub Pages](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39962114/jekyll-site-wont-display-on-github-pages)
- https://github.com/mmistakes/minimal-mistakes/issues/951

My repository is here: https://github.com/PlatosTwin/WUA/tree/gh-pages/docs.

And the live site is here: https://platostwin.github.io/WUA/.

[What the live page looks like.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BudOB.png)

[What the local page looks like.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oJ84E.png)

I suspect my theme customizations are to blame but am not expert enough at Jekyll to know where to look or what might have gone wrong. Any ideas on how to get the local and live page in sync, with the correct styling?

Thanks in advance for any advice!

Answer (score 2):

Solved! It turns out that simply commenting out `baseurl: ""`, in `_config.yml` does the trick. Thanks to the posts on [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48197580/jekyll-theme-does-not-work-on-github-pages-but-works-locally) StackOverflow for the pointer.